# How to avoid rejected execution exception while using ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, animation

So here's the problem.

I've been trying to move a png image of a phone on a linear direction which I have been successful at. The problem is when I try to stop it using the `exec.shutdownNow();` command.

[image: picture of how things look]

Don't get caught on the absence of Graphics, I deleted a big part of the code to make things simpler here,

```
public static ScheduledExecutorService exec1 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
int xphone = 200;
exec1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                g.drawImage(phone, xphone, 1050, 100, 100, null);
                xphone += 50;
                if(xphone >= 550) exec1.shutdownNow();
            }
        }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```